# is there an optimal amazon s3 region to use from dubai / UAE?

Tags: amazon-s3

my application does large file storage and retrieval to the amazon s3 service.  users in dubai report terrible latency.  i notice that there are no s3 regions that are 'close' to dubai, and i think that the UAE has a firewall that severely limits traffic to the outside world.

anyone have experience with this?  is there an optimal s3 region that would be best used from within dubai?

Answer (score 1):

My girlfrienb is in vacation in UAE right now. I have ssh on her android pad to configure OpenVPN. When I set OpenVPN to server in http://www.hetzner.de/en/ (germany) she has the best experience. I set UDP connection for OpenVPN.